# Parse soapMessage XML as String and search it with XPath in Java

Tags: java, xpath, soap, asmx

I have a problem which I cannot solve.
I have SOAP response which I get from the web service, then I parse it to String and then pass it to method in which I want to find car by id. **I constantly get NPE if I use Node or 0 list length if I use NodeList.** As a test, I want to get the first car.

SoapResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <ShowAllCarsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <ShowAllCarsResult>
            <Car>
               <Id>1</Id>
               <Make>Mercedes-Benz</Make>
               <Model>C63 AMG</Model>
               <YearOfMake>2007</YearOfMake>
               <Horsepower>450</Horsepower>
               <Displacement>6300</Displacement>
            </Car>
            <Car>
               <Id>2</Id>
               <Make>Lexus</Make>
               <Model>LC 500</Model>
               <YearOfMake>2020</YearOfMake>
               <Horsepower>471</Horsepower>
               <Displacement>5000</Displacement>
            </Car>
            <Car>
               <Id>3</Id>
               <Make>Ferrari</Make>
               <Model>488 GTB</Model>
               <YearOfMake>2018</YearOfMake>
               <Horsepower>661</Horsepower>
               <Displacement>3900</Displacement>
            </Car>
            <Car>
               <Id>4</Id>
               <Make>Rimac</Make>
               <Model>Concept Two</Model>
               <YearOfMake>2021</YearOfMake>
               <Horsepower>1914</Horsepower>
               <Displacement>0</Displacement>
            </Car>
         </ShowAllCarsResult>
      </ShowAllCarsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here I get soapMessage:

```
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", serverURI);

    SOAPBody body = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();
    QName bodyName = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "ShowAllCars" );
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/" + "ShowAllCars");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    return soapMessage;
}
```

Here I parse it to String:

```
private static String parseXmlToString(SOAPMessage soapMessage) {
    final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
                new DOMSource(soapMessage.getSOAPPart()),
                new StreamResult(sw));
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return sw.toString();
}
```

Here I try to search that String with XPath:

```
private static void findCarById(String xml) {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    System.out.println(xml);
    Document document;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    String expression = "soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ShowAllCarsResponse/ShowAllCarsResult/Car[1]";
    try {
        NodeList result = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("RESULT");
        System.out.println(result.item(0).getTextContent());
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As a final step I call all in one method:

```
private static void createSoapEnvelope() throws Exception {
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    String url = "http://localhost:49883/CarsService.asmx";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

    String xml = parseXmlToString(soapResponse);
    findCarById(xml);

    soapConnection.close();
}
```

When I call `System.out.println(result.item(0).getTextContent());`
I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hr.algebra.controllers.SOAPController.findCarById(SOAPController.java:117)
at hr.algebra.controllers.SOAPController.createSoapEnvelope(SOAPController.java:39)
at hr.algebra.controllers.SOAPController.btnSearchPressed(SOAPController.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:276)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace, that will help.

Comment: Here, I added. @stridecolossus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using SAAJ for your call, why not use the same API to read the response?

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

String ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
SOAPBody responseBody = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();

SOAPElement allCarsResponse = (SOAPElement) responseBody.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, "ShowAllCarsResponse").item(0);
SOAPElement allCarsResult = (SOAPElement) allCarsResponse.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, "ShowAllCarsResult").item(0);
NodeList allCars = allCarsResult.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, "Car");

SOAPElement firstCar = (SOAPElement) allCars.item(0);
String id = firstCar.getElementsByTagNameNS(ns, "Id").item(0).getTextContent();
```

If you insist of using XPath, then you can do it like this:

```
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

NamespaceContext nsContext = new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return "http://tempuri.org/".equals(namespaceURI) ? "tmp" : null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        return "tmp".equals(prefix) ? "http://tempuri.org/" : null;
    }
};

SOAPBody responseBody = soapResponse.getSOAPBody();
Document document = responseBody.extractContentAsDocument();
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(nsContext);

XPathExpression expr = xpath
        .compile("/tmp:ShowAllCarsResponse/tmp:ShowAllCarsResult/tmp:Car[1]/tmp:Id");
String id = expr.evaluate(document);
```

I find the second approach overkill since you can traverse the API by going from element to element.

*I've just taken the first `Car` in the XML sequence like you were trying to do in your question. To search by `Id` you can loop in the first example and `break;` when you find your car, or update the XPath expression in the second example respectively.*

Comment: Thank you very much, it was of a big help!

Comment: This is not only the best answer! but also presented the complete solution. Not a brief intro how to solve something.